# Error when submitting package in Julia

Tags: git, github, julia, scientific-computing

I'm trying to make changes to a package in Julia but every time I submit I encounter the following bug

```
INFO: Forking jiahao/GSL.jl to blah
Enter host password for user 'blah':
ERROR: Unknown value
Line: 0
Around: ...HTTP/1.1 422 Unproces...
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Have you successfully forked the repo from the GitHub website?

Comment: Yup, the package is installed in my computer in the usual place. Most functions worked fine, one didn't, so I created my own branch, fixed it and tried to submit it.

Comment: I'm wondering if your local git repo is configured in a typical fashion for submitting pull requests on GitHub.  What's the output of `git remote -v` on your local machine?

Comment: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Comment: You did this from your local `GSL` directory?

Comment: No sorry, here's the result from GSL

Comment: origin https://github.com/jiahao/GSL.jl.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:jiahao/GSL.jl.git (push)

Comment: Did you successfully complete all the [Package Develop Initial Setup](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#package-development)?  You have a GitHub account, yes?

Comment: I do have a githhub account, but on going through the setup a second time I found I had a problem with ssh agent forwarding (when running ssh -v example.com). It says "Could not open socks configuration file" and then "assuming all networks local". I assume I need to create this file to tell it how to connect via proxy but I don't feel qualified to do that. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @JohnDuffy Please either mark the answer below about setting up SSH or submit an answer to your own question stating what you said in the comments.  Otherwise this question will continue to show up as unanswered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using Julia's `Pkg.submit("PackageName")` to create a GitHub pull request requires that all of the steps listed in Julia's [Package Develop Initial Setup](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#package-development) be completed successfully first.

In particular, your GitHub SSH keys need to be setup correctly.

Note that you can still create a pull request *"old school"* style by forking the package on GitHub (just click the button), modify/test your personal fork, and then submit a pull request on GitHub.